# Determine when application cache item will timeout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-1.1

In ASP.NET, when storing a value in the application cache with absolute expiry is there a method to retrieve the date/time when the item will expire?  The application cache item will be refreshed if expired based on user requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method signature on the HttContext.Cache object which allows you to specify a method to be called in the event that a Cached item is removed when you set a new Cache item.

Define yourself a method that'll allow you to process that information, whether you want it to re-submit the item to the Applcation Cache, email you about it, log it in the Event Log, whatever suits your needs.

Hope that helps,
Pascal

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've understood your question right, but I'll give it a try: I believe there is no way to actually figure out, when a certain cache-item is going to expire. In most scenarios, I use a delegate passed in as a parameter (CacheItemRemovedCallback) when adding objects to the cache, so I get notified when the item gets kicked out.

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

use the CacheItemRemovedCallback; your object may get kicked from the cache earlier than you expect anyway